# w5100 Shield fails to initialize Ethernet when certain SD card is inserted

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Arduino IDE 1.8.9  macOS,
Ethernet lib 2.0.0,
SD lib 1.2.4

Atmega2560 + Ethernet Shield w5100

Got a strange problem.  My w5100 Shield is unable to setup network if some of SD cards is inserted, while the other SD cards doesn't cause problem.  All SD cards are 256mb, and are formatted by SDFormatter.  **SD card itself works properly in both cases.**

The issue can be reproduced with simple sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Ethernet.h> 

#define PIN_SD 4

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SD.begin(PIN_SD)) {
    Serial.println("SD fail");
  }

  pinMode(PIN_SD, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PIN_SD, HIGH);

  byte mac[6] = {0x52, 0xa0, 0xe9, 0x90, 0x47, 0x28};
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Net Fail");
  }
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I tried to drill down the issue, and found the problem comes from `W5100Class::softReset()` in `w5100.cpp`. Soft reset is triggered during init(), and function fails to get expected value from `MR`(Mode Register).

To make it clear, I intrduce a few outputs to `softReset(void)` as follows:

```
// Soft reset the Wiznet chip, by writing to its MR register reset bit
uint8_t W5100Class::softReset(void)
{
 uint16_t count=0;

 Serial.println("Wiznet soft reset");
 Serial.println(readMR(), HEX);
 // write to reset bit
 writeMR(0x80);
 // then wait for soft reset to complete
 do {
 uint8_t mr = readMR();
 Serial.print("mr=");
 Serial.println(mr, HEX);
 if (mr == 0) return 1;
 delay(1);
 } while (++count < 20);
 return 0;
}
```

Here are the serial outputs with good SD card.

```
w5100 init
Wiznet soft reset
0
mr=0
Wiznet soft reset
0
mr=0
w5100.cpp: detect W5100 chip
Wiznet soft reset
0
mr=0
chip is W5100
w5100 found
172.10.0.70
```

Here are the serial outputs with problematic SD card.

```
w5100 init
Wiznet soft reset
FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
Wiznet soft reset
FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
w5100.cpp: detect W5100 chip
Wiznet soft reset
FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
mr=FF
Net Fail
```

In abnormal case, `MR` stays `0xff` around soft reset.

Any idea on this?

It seems SD card initialization causes corruption/overflow somewhere in memory. I tried to figure out the difference between 2 groups of SD cards. For now:

- If files are copied from mac to SD card with the same adapter, it's much faster to write BAD card.
- With extra output in SD lib, I found GOOD cards are `SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2`, and BAD cards are `SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1`. Since there's no enough sample (actual-3, 2 BAD, 1 GOOD), I cannot tell this is the keypoint.

`Sd2Card.h`

```
/** Standard capacity V1 SD card */
uint8_t const SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1 = 1;
/** Standard capacity V2 SD card */
uint8_t const SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2 = 2;
/** High Capacity SD card */
uint8_t const SD_CARD_TYPE_SDHC = 3;
```

**Update** 20200701:

I've got more SD cards for test. It turns out SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1 is irrelevant, as some GOOD cards are SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1.

It looks the problem only happends to the cards with same chip/batch. Filesystem parameters are exactly the same.  So could be SD chip issue...

```
Card type:         SD1
Clusters:          15608
Blocks x Cluster:  32
Total Blocks:      499456

Volume type is:    FAT16
Volume size (Kb):  249728
Volume size (Mb):  243
Volume size (Gb):  0.24
```

**update** 20200703

The problem is actually from `Sd2Card::init()` in file `Sd2Card.cpp`

```
  while ((status_ = cardCommand(CMD0, 0)) != R1_IDLE_STATE) {
    unsigned int d = millis() - t0;
    if (d > SD_INIT_TIMEOUT) {
      error(SD_CARD_ERROR_CMD0);
      goto fail;
    }
  }
```

As long as `cardCommand(CMD0, 0)` is called with BAD SD card, ethernet will fail.

Comment: Hi roger, any progress on this issue ?